How can I find the minimum integrals faster?
Let 0 ≤ p₁ <p₂ <...p ≤1 be "n" separated points and let
$$L(x; p_k) = \frac{\prod_{j=1, j \ne k}^n (x-p_j)}{\prod_{j=1, j \ne k}^n (p_k-p_j)},$$
(1)
denote the well-known Lagrange interpolation polynomials. Now, based on (1) define the
following n-variable function
$$F_n(p_1, p_2,...,p_n) = \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^n |L(x; p_k)|dx$$
(2)
$$= \int_0^1 (|L(x; p_1)|+|L(x; p_2)|+...+|L(x; p_n)|)dx.$$
Our computational problem is to numerically minimize the above function (2) for n = 2,3,...,10.
The important property
$$\sum_{k=1}^n L(x; p_k) = 1 \implies \sum_{k=1}^n |L(x; p_k)| \ge \left| \sum_{k=1}^n L(x; p_k) \right|$$
$$ \implies 1 = \int_0^1 1 dx \leq \int_0^1 \sum_{k=1}^n |L(x; p_k)| dx = F_n(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n), $$ which is therefore equivalent to $$ F_n(p_1, p_2, ..., p_n) \geq 1 $$
for every  $$0 \leq p_1 < p_2 < ... < p_n \leq 1,$$
Now, derive and compute the similar results for  $$n = 3, ..., 10$$ numerically by designing a computational code and step  $$h = 0.01$$. In other words, determine the separated points for each special "n" and then determine the minimum value of  $$F_n$$ for those obtained points just like the above mentioned example.
We first create non-repeating permutations to construct the Lagrange interpolator polynomial.
    n = 4;
list = {};
P[j] := 0.01*j;
ss = Table[P[j], {j, 0, 100}]
per = Subsets[ss, {4}]
len = Length[per]

Then after finding the integrals, We find the minimum of these integrals.
For n=4 the number of different states is 4082925 which takes 15 minutes to run for every 10000.
For [s = 400 001, s ≤ 450 000, s ++, f = Integrate [
Sum [
Abs [
(Product [x - per [s] [j], {j, Delete [Range [n], k]}])
/ (Product [per [s] [k] - per [s] [j], {j, Delete [Range [n], k]}])
],{k, 1, n}],
{x, 0, 1}];
Print ["F (n=", n, ",", per [s], ",s=", s, ") =", f];
 AppendTo [list, f]];
Min [list]

Is there a way to make the program run faster?

(* Specify the number of nodes. *)
n = 4;

(* Define the symbolic Lagrange polynomials. *)
ClearAll[L];
L = Table[
   x |-> Evaluate[
     Divide[
      Times[
       Product[(x - Indexed[p, j]), {j, 1, k - 1}],
       Product[(x - Indexed[p, j]), {j, k + 1, n}]
       ],
      Times[
       Product[(Indexed[p, k] - Indexed[p, j]), {j, 1, k - 1}],
       Product[(Indexed[p, k] - Indexed[p, j]), {j, k + 1, n}]
       ]
      ]
     ],
   {k, 1, n}];

(* Define the antiderivative of the symbolic Lagrange polynomials. *)
IntL = Table[x |-> Evaluate[Integrate[L[[k]][x], x]], {k, 1, n}];

(* Create an array of nodes, including 0 and 1. *)
q = Join[{0}, Table[Indexed[p, i], {i, 1, n}], {1}];

(* Compute the objective function. To remove the absolute values we \
exploit that the signedness of the Lagrange polynomials is known for \
each interval defined by the nodes. *)
F = p |-> Evaluate[Together[Sum[
      Plus[
       Sum[(-1)^(i + k) (IntL[[k]][Indexed[q, i + 1]] - 
           IntL[[k]][Indexed[q, i]]), {i, 1, k}],
       Sum[(-1)^(i + 1 + k) (IntL[[k]][Indexed[q, i + 1]] - 
           IntL[[k]][Indexed[q, i]]), {i, k + 1, Length[q] - 1}]
       ],
      {k, 1, n}]]];

(* Some initial guess for the nodes. *)
p0 = MovingAverage[Subdivide[0., 1., n], 2];

(* Use FindMinimum to find a local(!) minimizer. *)
sol = FindMinimum[{F[p], LessEqual @@ q}, {p, p0}]

